# p-inputSwitch true o false usando ngClass

Tags: angular

Buenas noches grupo soy nuevo en lo que es angular y tengo un pequeño problema con el p-inputSwitch.
Bueno yo tengo un servicio que trae un campo Estado que puede ser '0' o '1' el cual lo necesito mostrar en los switchs y lo que yo hice es un [ngClass] que seria esto:

```
<p-inputSwitch [ngClass]="{'p-inputswitch p-component ':deposito.estado=='0', 'p-inputswitch p-component p-inputswitch-checked':deposito.estado=='1'}" styleClass="mt-1"  "></p-inputSwitch>
```

Eso me retorna estos switchs:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno la cosa es que puedo modificar el swicth que esta desactivado, mejor dicho de false a true pero los que estan activos se quedan ahi, cuando le doy click no hace el cambio de true a false.

Esa seria mi problemita :D de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ser que el valor no sea ni 1 ni 0, prueba a ponerlo en el html {{deposito.estado}}, puede que sea true o false.
Suele pasar que el valor cuando lo guardamos en la base de datos tipo mysql, el boolean sea de tipo int (pequeño), o en otros casos sea varchar, y lo transformamos a 1 o 0.
Si es así hay que tener en cuenta si procede de un cambio en el html o de la base de datos.
Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Voy a intentar explicarme algo mejor.
La idea principal es si puedes añadir en tu código html (más o menos)

```
Estado: {{ deposito.estado | json }}
<p-inputSwitch [ngClass]="{'p-inputswitch p-component ':deposito.estado=='0', 'p-inputswitch p-component p-inputswitch-checked':deposito.estado=='1'}" styleClass="mt-1"  "></p-inputSwitch>
```

Lo que creo que puede estar ocurriendo, es que cuando trabajas en html y javascript, cuando modificas el switch, los valores de estado deberían de ser true o false.

Pero cuando se guardan en la base de datos y se recogen, será como 1 o 0.
Otra cosa que no veo es como modificas el valor de p-switch, ya que no veo ningún model ni formcontrolName.
Quiero pensar que hay otro sitio donde lo modificas.
Espero que haya quedado un poco más claro.

Comment: Pudiste haber editado tu otra respuesta en lugar de agregar una nueva respuesta.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu respuesta, y hace una respuesta completa. Mira por favor [answer]